# XML/Class/ .swf import

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, import, swfloader

I'm not entirely sure of myself when it comes to as3 but seem to understand 'most' things. I'm having a bit of an issue and hope that someone may be able to lend me their brainpower:

**I have a .fla that calls on multiple class files. Within one of those Classes, I'm calling some XML that contains .png files (12 in total). These import fine but, the moment I change them over to .swf files I get this error:**

```
ERROR on ImageLoader "photo1" (maps/eq-15.swf): ERROR #2035: URL Not Found. 
URL:///C/....(file location Goes Here)
```

Does anyone understand the error of my way?

I can post more of the code I speak of but unsure of which pieces to post as to not confuse the situation.

Comment: For SWF file, you need to use Loader and where ImageLoader come from?

Comment: *feeling stupid

I will research further then, tku.

Comment: Do I need to do something more than just swop out ImageLoader with SWFLoader? Probably... I'll look into it more.

Comment: Target files are just missing, that's most probably why.

Comment: Why use loaders? Maybe statically link em in your SWF if they are really static, and call it a day?

Comment: **Show minimum code required to re-create this issue from a blank page to current error**. You tagged `SWFloader` Flex component so are you [**using this?**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html) or maybe it's like this [**Greensock code**](https://greensock.com/asdocs/com/greensock/loading/SWFLoader.html)? Just show us what you're doing...

Comment: i'm an idiot and ...the winner is "Target files are just missing, that's most probably why." --Organis

Too many files running around and too focused on what could go wrong that i missed moving the files to the correct directory.

Thank you all for your fast responses and I do realize that I did not give too much information to go on either (this project is quite large, 18 databases, 8 class files, countless swf files imported). I may just be overloaded. Again, thank you all!